# Normalizing values in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have an data table I wish to perform some numeric analysis on for that I need all the values to be in the same range. 0..1.

I have a somewhat slow and longhanded way of accomplishing this but would like a more straigt forward performant solution to my problem

What I need to do is:

group by projectid
with in each project take the average of each of the values and divide by the largest average for the entire set.

currently I have

```
select avg(foo * 1.0)/ (Select MAX(IL) FROM (select avg(foo * 1.0) as IL from table group by     
                                             ProjectID) tbl)
from table
```

so if the list is

```
projectid  | foo
-----------------
1          | 1
1          | 2
2          | 4
2          | 2
```

the largest average is 3 and the result should therefor be

0.5,1

where the first is the average for projectId 1 divided by 3 and the second is the average for projectId 2 divided by 3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/57a00/18)

```
select
    Projectid,
    avg(cast(foo as decimal(29, 2))) / max(avg(cast(foo as decimal(29, 2)))) over ()
from tbl1
group by Projectid
```

Comment: Does not produce the expected result. The result is 0.333333 and 1

Comment: No, result is 0.5 and 1, just checked it in SQL Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/57a00/18

Comment: Now it's correct yes but then again this was not the version displayed or on the fiddle link when I wrote the comment :)

Comment: Yes, I've edited it when I saw that results are incorrect, about 20 minutes ago

Answer (score 1):

```
;with cte as
(
    select projectid, AVG(foo) av
    from yourtable
    group by projectid
)
    select *,
        av/(select MAX(av) from cte)
    from cte
```

Comment: In the real scenario i'm using both sum and average and have 20+ columns any way to cater for that?